# SQL. Joining records from 3 or more tables based on dates

Tags: sql, join

My tables look like this(just an example):

table1:

```
TIME     |data1
1.01.2018|aaa
2.01.2018|bbb
```

table2:

```
TIME     |data2
1.01.2018|abcd
2.01.2018|cd
```

table3:

```
TIME     |data3
1.01.2018|
2.01.2018|d
```

Now what i would like to do is take the data from table2 and put it in the table1 where there are missing records. If there is no record in all tables for that date, then the data in data column is NULL. The data copied to table1 needs to be the same date as in the table2. and if there is no same date in table1 as it is in table2, that date is created.

So far i have tried with this code, but the data copied is not valid. If there is a missing day in some of the tables, that missing day is created in time column, but the data in data column is incorect.

```
    SELECT DISTINCT table1.time,table1.data,table2.time,table2.data,table3.time,table3.data
    FROM table1
    LEFT JOIN table2 ON table1.time=table2.time 
    LEFT JOIN table3 ON table1.time=table3.time
```

**EDIT**
This is how the output should look like:
For example, there was no data in table3 for data3 for  that specific date, so the cell is empty.

```
TIME     |data1|data2|data3|
1.01.2018|aaa  |abcd |     |
2.01.2018|bbb  |  cd |   d |
```

Comment: Can you kindly add the desired output?

Comment: I guess you might want to look at [UNION](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/sql/sql-unions-clause.htm)

Comment: To simplify your question: You want to have a copy of each record in every table, right?

Comment: @SudiptaMondal The UNION just copies data together. It doesnt match the data from tables with the same date.

Comment: @greijner I have edited my post with the desired output from the sql query

Comment: You should change your sample input a bit. Because f.e. in table3 there are both dates. Just add some records to show that either date can be missing in either table.

Answer (score 2):

You need a full join instead of a left join. (you didn't specify the backend. Here the sample is with MS SQL) ie:

```
SELECT  
coalesce(table1."time",table2."time", table3."time") as "time",
         table1.data1,table2.data2,table3.data3
    FROM table1
    full JOIN table2 ON table1."time"=table2."time" 
    full JOIN table3 ON table1."time"=table3."time" ;
```

Output:

```
Time    data1   data2   data3
1.01.2018   aaa abcd    (null)
2.01.2018   bbb cd      d
```

EDIT: The distinct in your code suggests you want only one row per day. Then it is not clear which column value should be used. Assuming any would do, you can do aggregation like this:

```
SELECT  
coalesce(table1."time",table2."time", table3."time") as "time",
         max(table1.data1) as data1,
         max(table2.data2) as data2,
         max(table3.data3) as data3
    FROM table1
    full JOIN table2 ON table1."time"=table2."time" 
    full JOIN table3 ON table1."time"=table3."time" 
  group by coalesce(table1."time",table2."time", table3."time");
```

Comment: Probably the best solution for this. And you even considered duplicates.  Btw, if you want to turn it into a more standard SQL then change the quoting of `[time]` to `"time"`. ;)

Comment: @LukStorms, thanks for the identifiers idea :) I was more concerned about the availability of coalesce() in all backends.

Comment: COALESCE is in the SQL-92 standard. So that would be fine in probably all RDBMS that respect themselves. With CONCAT it would be an issue, because although most RDBMS's have a CONCAT, f.e. Oracle only accepts 2 params. (I sometimes wonder if Oracle never hires golfcoders in their dev teams)

Comment: @user2980341, yes it is supported. Probably you edited the code and introduced a syntax error?

Comment: @CetinBasoz sorry already deleted my comment. Yes FULL JOIN is supported in SSMS, it was an error on my side in code.

Comment: Maybe the only thing that's still missing is that requirement for when the date is missing in all tables.  But I doubt there's a "standard" SQL way to generate a range of dates.

Comment: @LukStorms Yes, i was thinking the same thing, what if the date is missing in all tables. 
And if the date is missing in my table1, then there is no record in query for other tables for that date. Any fix for this?

Comment: @user2980341 Since you're using SSMS, then you're on a MS SQL Server. In that case one option is to use a recursive CTE. For example : `;with RCTE_DATERANGE as 
(
 select cast('2018-01-01' as date) dt, cast('2018-01-03' as date) as max_dt
 union all
 select dateadd(day, 1, dt), max_dt
 from RCTE_DATERANGE
 where dt < max_dt
)
select dt 
from RCTE_DATERANGE;`.  And use that to join the other tables. Actually, left joining them to that daterange would also be fine.

Comment: @LukStorms Thanks for answers. What if i have thousands records and somwhere in there a table is missing a date and i dont know what date?

Comment: Well, first you need to fill in the minimum date and maximum date in that recursive cte. I'm sure you know how to get them from those 3 tables.  Then when you left join those tables to the RCTE, the "time" field of the joined table(s) can be null in the result if the table doesn't have that date. So then just add the WHERE clause `WHERE (t1.[time] IS NULL OR t2.[time] IS NULL OR t3.[time] IS NULL)`

Answer (score 1):

Start the process with

```
SELECT [DISTINCT] TIME FROM TABLE1
UNION [DISTINCT]
SELECT [DISTINCT] TIME FROM TABLE2
UNION [DISTINCT]
SELECT [DISTINCT] TIME FROM TABLE3
```

And then LEFT JOIN the three tables to that.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
with cte as (Select time from table1 union Select time from table2 union Select time from table3)
    SELECT cte.time,table1.data as data1,table2.data as data2,table3.data as data3
    FROM cte
    LEFT JOIN table1 ON table1.time=cte.time 
    LEFT JOIN table2 ON cte.time=table2.time 
    LEFT JOIN table3 ON cte.time=table3.time
```

Answer (score 0):

Apply simple left join after union on.

```
DECLARE @t1 table
(
TIMEDate1 DATE
,Data1 VARCHAR(50)
)

DECLARE @t2 table
(
TIMEDate2 DATE
,Data2 VARCHAR(50)
)

DECLARE @t3 table
(
TIMEDate3 DATE
,Data3 VARCHAR(50)
)


insert @t1 (TIMEDate1,Data1 ) select getdate(),'aaa'
insert @t1 (TIMEDate1,Data1 ) select getdate()+1,'bbb'

insert @t2 (TIMEDate2,Data2 ) select getdate(),'abcd'
insert @t2 (TIMEDate2,Data2 ) select getdate()+1,'cd'

insert @t3 (TIMEDate3,Data3 ) select getdate(),''
 insert @t3 (TIMEDate3,Data3 ) select getdate()+1,'d'

SELECT t.TIMEDate,t1.Data1,t2.Data2,t3.Data3 
FROM (
SELECT distinct TIMEDate1  as  TIMEDate FROM @t1
UNION 
SELECT distinct TIMEDate2 as TIMEDate FROM @t2
UNION 
SELECT distinct TIMEDate3 as TIMEDate FROM @t3
) t
left JOIN @t1 t1 ON t1.TIMEDate1 = t.TIMEDate
left JOIN @t2 t2 ON t2.TIMEDate2 = t.TIMEDate
left JOIN @t3 t3 ON t3.TIMEDate3 = t.TIMEDate
--order by t1.TIMEDate1 asc
```

Answer (score 0):

The SQL below is just an alternative for inserting the missing dates into Table1.

```
--
-- insert those into Table1 that are in Table2 but not in Table1
--
insert into Table1 ("time", data1)
select "time", data2
from Table2 as t2
where not exists
(
  select 1
  from Table1 as t1
  where t1."time" = t2."time"
);

--
-- insert those into Table1 that are in Table3 but not in Table1
--
insert into Table1 ("time", data1)
select "time", data3
from Table3 as t3
where not exists
(
  select 1
  from Table1 as t1
  where t1."time" = t3."time"
);
```

Then add the dates that are still missing in Table1 after all that.
Below is an example for MS SQL Server :

```
;with RCTE_DATERANGE as 
( 
   select min([time]) as dt, max([time]) as max_dt
   from Table1
   union all 
   select dateadd(day, 1, dt), max_dt 
   from RCTE_DATERANGE where dt < max_dt 
) 
insert into Table1 ([time])
select dt 
from RCTE_DATERANGE AS rcte
where not exists
(
  select 1
  from Table1 as t1
  where t1.[time] = rcte.dt
);

-- Just checking
;with RCTE_DATERANGE as 
( 
   select min([time]) as dt, max([time]) as max_dt
   from Table1
   union all 
   select dateadd(day, 1, dt), max_dt 
   from RCTE_DATERANGE where dt < max_dt 
) 
select rcte.dt, t1.[time] as time1, t2.[time] as time2, t3.[time] as [time3], t1.data1, t2.data2, t3.data3  
from RCTE_DATERANGE AS rcte
full join Table1 t1 on t1.[time] = rcte.dt
full join Table2 t2 on t2.[time] = rcte.dt
full join Table3 t3 on t3.[time] = rcte.dt;
```